# How to solve this error in Unity? (System.Net.Sockets)

Tags: c#, android, sockets, unity-game-engine

I got much help through Stackoverflow.
Recently, I checked this error when I used Unity.

**SystemException: 'System.Net.Sockets' are supported only with Unity Android Pro. Referenced from assembly 'Assembly-CSharp'**

To solve this error, I did it as follows :

1. I would open up Visual Studio and do a Find in Files for "System.Net.Sockets". The file name was 'UDPReceive.cs'.
   I searched script for finding script error. But I didn't find script error.
2. I did find another solution. The solution is to add '#if UNITY_EDITOR' at the very top of any file that uses 'System.Net.Sockets' and '#endif' at the bottom of files. But this error occured continuingly.
3. I deleted 'Assembly-CSharp' file and 'UDPReceive.cs'. But this error was not solved and more errors occur X_X

So, I wanna solve this error. 
Could you notify solution of this error to me?

Is there only solution using paid Android Pro?

+) My Unity Version is 4.6.3 & Unity Pro Version (Internal Develop Version)

Comment: What Unity version? NVM Got it you have 4.6.3

Comment: Are you using any Socket or network class from System.Net?

Comment: My Unity Version is 4.6.3 Pro Version

Comment: Yeah, there is any Socket class in project file. This project was originally made for PC Platform & Oculus Version. (Actually, I got project file from my senior. T_T)

Comment: This doesn't solve your problem but it's worth noting that Unity made this a paid Android "feature" with Unity 3.5.6.  [Source](http://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-3.5.6)  (See the 4th bullet under Fixes)

Comment: Is this problem solved? If so how did you solve it?

Comment: @Programmer I don't solve this problem perfectly. Most reasonable method is to update Unity 5 because Unity 5 Ver. supports Socket.Net function. I attach related link : https://support.gamesparks.net/support/discussions/topics/1000052675

Comment: I think that's fine. If you are allowed to use Unity 5 then go for it. If what you are doing requres the 4.6 version then you have must have Android Pro on top of Unity Pro for it to work. Android Pro license cost $1500. There is a socket plugin called **Good ol' Sockets** that cost only $25. That's another option you have https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/13166. Again, if you are fine with Unity 5 then stick with it. The socket namespace is free to use on that version.